# Attribute selected option by text not value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, drop-down-menu, attributes

When clicking a table row, the row text copies up to the inputs above for editing purposes. The text copies up just fine, but I cannot get all the selects right. My text isn't the same as the value (for every select, it is for the third column), so I cannot use the .val() of the select.

I need to attribute/prop selected where  text matches the beginning of  text AND whether or not it is reimbursable (third column). Ideas? jsfiddle.net/7vLdxddr/14

```
$('.table').on('click', 'tr', function () {

                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                }
                else {
                    $('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < $(this).find("td").length; i++) {
                    // fill input values
                    $(this).closest("table").find("th").eq(i).find("input:text").val($(this).find("td").eq(i).text());
                    // fill selects
                    $(this).closest("table").find("th").eq(i).find("select").val($(this).find("td").eq(i).text());
                }
            });
```

Comment: loop through options, check text, if matches, set selected property.

Comment: Example? The fiddle is set up.

Comment: Can the text values of the select be changed or are these values dynamically generated?

Answer (score 1):

If you do like this, you don't need to have values that equals to the text.

```
    $('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            $('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }

    // fill inputs
    $(this).closest("table").find("th").eq(0).find("input:text").val($(this).find("td").eq(0).text());

    // fill selects      
   var text = $(this).find("td").eq(1).text();
   var text3 = $(this).find("td").eq(2).text();

   $(this).closest("table").find("th").eq(1).find("select option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(text) >= 0 && $(this).text().indexOf($(this).closest("table").find("th").eq(2).find('select option[value="' + text3 + '"]').text()) > 0;
}).prop('selected', true);        

   $(this).closest("table").find("th").eq(2).find('select').val(text3);
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/7vLdxddr/15/

Comment: How can I add onto this with indexOf()? Some of my tds have whitespace or dashes. http://jsfiddle.net/7vLdxddr/12/

Comment: Almost. I don't want the selects to change, just match the first word and select that option.

Comment: What does that mean? You don't want "the select to change", but you want to "select that option"?

Comment: Let me change my example.

Comment: Okay, it's more complicated than I initially explained. Firstly, I need the option (from the given dropdown options) to select if the text in the td is a close match. For example, "Plane" should select the "Plane - ..." option. Also, my reimbursable selects do match values AND the Plane option is dependent on the reimbursable coulmn. http://jsfiddle.net/7vLdxddr/14/

Comment: It doesn't entirely work because of the complexity of my table, but thank you. I ended up hardcoding what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the values of the select values to reflect the text coming in from the click (i.e. `cir` to `circle`, `sq` to `square` and it works perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/7vLdxddr/10/

What your code was trying to do was select a input with value `circle`, but the value of the `circle` field was `cir` so it was not being selected properly.

Comment: But the question states "My text isn't the same as the value", so just modifying the value might not be a good answer.

Comment: @Kristoffer Ah true, mine would be the fastest solution for hardcoded values, but if it's dynamic (or grabbed from another website, etc.) and it needs to be matched then your answer works best. I guess a better understanding of the question at hand is needed.